How to show stack trace line numbers in .NET MAUI Production app log files
I have probably done 2 days of research online and cannot find anything concrete, especially for Android/iOS .NET MAUI apps. Does anyone know how I can make this a possibility?
It's frustrating looking at client log files and just getting a method name in the stack trace instead of detail lines with line and position numbers as you would expect when you run the app in debug.
What settings do I need turned on?
Thanks in advance.

How are you currently logging? What exactly are you logging?

we are using Firebase, AppCenter and MetroLog MAUI. What I really care about the MetroLog output since we send it as an attachment to AppCenter and also allow our clients to send logs directly to us. But line numbers never print out in release builds. @Julian

And are you logging the exception object to MetroLog or just the message of the exception?

I am logging the exception yes. I have tested this with debug and release builds. Line numbers show in debug builds but don't in release builds. I have the whole stack traces printed. So I know there must be a setting to get that at the sacrifice of performance, I am just curious what it is. @Julian

Do you want to enable the line numbers in the release builds?

@user10627299 yes I do!

@steve It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn
